# Folder with a question mark on purchased Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, software

I just got my MacBook Pro mid 2012 laptop and stupid me did something to it, now I have a flashing folder with a question mark. The previous owner said she accidentally deleted the software when she was transferring her things to the other laptop.

I rang AppleCare and I did all these things to try and solve it but all it come up with is a password but I don't know the password. Is this a common thing? Should I take it to Apple Store?

Not in contact with the seller.

Answer (score 1):

Folder with the question mark usually means "no valid device to boot from".

Try to boot to recovery (if any exists) by keeping pressing command + r when turning on the Mac. You should be able to reinstall it there.

If still fails you may try Mac OS X internet recovery (cmd+option+r keeps pressed while pressing power button)

If still fails, get someone with a working Mac with App store to get you a Mac OS X El Capitan Installer following the steps listed here:
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372

Make sure the usb disk itself is a bootable instance (as in some cases it is blocked by hardware design).

When the bootable USB disk is plugged in, hold down the option when turning on to get a selectable boot device list and you should be able to see a disk to install to (if, not there is not any, it will be a hardware issue then -> go to Apple store or get someone else to fix).

After in recovery mode if seeing a disc to install to: feel free to erase the disk as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) (==HFS+) and install your instance with your Apple ID.